# Verification of vector field notation

Tags: calculus

This might be a silly question, but when you have a vector field given by:

$$F(x,y,z)= \langle 0,2,1 \rangle$$

Do you assume that:
 **F** $=(2y)j + (z)k$ or **F**$=2j + k$?

Picture of question for reference:

[image]

Comment: $F(x, y, z) = (0, 2, 1)$ would mean that $F$ is constantly equal to the vector $(0, 2, 1)$, or $2j + k$. I'm not sure what is meant by $\langle 0, 2, 1 \rangle$ if this is not a typo. This notation is usually used for an element of projective space.

Comment: @Chistopher Gadzisnki Thank you Chistopher. I added a picture of the question my professor posted as reference. Perhaps it will shed some light.

Comment: Ah, so this is just an alternative notation for a vector that I haven't seen too much. It without a doubt means the former: $F$ is a constant vector field.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would clearly go for the second option unless some unconventional notations have been clearly stated previously.

I then see two remaining possibilities:

- either (x,y,z) are generic variables in this case the vector field is constant
- or (x,y,z) stands for a particular point in space and only one value
  of the field is therefore given.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! Very helpful!